# Gallery Sort Order

Tags: gallery, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gallery sort order](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/gallery-sort-order)

Photos taken by the camera app are sorted newest to oldest by the default gallery app. All the other folders are sorted from oldest to newest.

Is there a way to adjust the sort order?

I am on CM702 on a TMO G2 (HTC Vision)