# gallery sort order

Tags: gallery, htc-wildfire

I have HTC Wildfire.

I used default gallery app, that ships with the phone to view photos.

What is the default sort order of the gallery app?

Sometimes, photos are in a particular order, after a month of so, they are in different order.

I don't know what is happening.

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/gallery-sort-order

Comment: @GAThrawn: Sorry, but answer is not available at the link that you mentioned

Comment: m-jm Yes, I know that there are no answers there yet. I was just pointing that question out as one to keep an eye on, as they're very similar questions and a future answer on there might help you out.

Comment: @GAThrawn: thank you for pointing out, I'll keep track on it

Answer (score 4):

I've had experience before on the Nexus One, this sort order is the **last modified**.

If you access your SD card from your PC this can sometimes scan your images folder and 'touch' the images with the last modified date then being updated.

That's how I've had random sort orders in the past!

Comment: @I-M-JM Could you mark as answered. It's a green tick on the left of the answer.