# Gallery images appearing in mixed up order

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, photos, gallery, media-scanner, date-and-time

I have an HTC One X with stock Android 4.1.1. As you know, Android 4.1 introduced a "nice" feature to the gallery which allows grouping images by events. Unfortunately, after this update I started to notice a very annoying and intermittent bug: sometimes, if I have a group with hundreds of images, some of them appear in jumbled up order. I use Dropbox to sync them to my PC, so I don't usually connect my phone via USB to the PC. After seeing this issue, I browsed via USB to some of the images that appear in the wrong position and it looks like the EXIF date is correct, but, for some reason, the phone shows a different hour for this images in the "Details" section. It appears as if it misreads the hour when indexing them, showing them as having been taken one hour before the date in the EXIF data.

I have tried to clear the cache of the `Media Storage` application and restart the phone, but, unfortunately, this did not do the trick and I think that a few more images got mixed up after it finished rescanning.

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this bug and how can it be fixed?

**PS:** I installed Total Commander on the phone and it displays the proper date for the images and it also picks them up in the expected order, so this is clearly a bug in the `Media Storage` app.

Comment: Three things come to my mind first: 1) timezone differences, 2) DST, 3) Exif-Date versus File-Date. Something might get messed up on sync (file-date wise). I'm not sure where the media-scanner takes the date+time from, Exif or file date, when both are available (well, when Exif is available -- file date always is available, of course).

Comment: @Izzy The pictures are taken in the same place (city) so timezone and DST issues should not occur, and I do have several similar sets from different cities that have the same issue. What I do see is that the date shown by Total Commander is different than the one shown in the `Details` section of the media gallery for the same picture, which makes me believe that `Media Storage` does not read the actual file date...

Comment: *pictures are taken in the same place (city) so timezone and DST issues should not occur* .||. *I use Dropbox to sync them to my PC* => Also same city? You can vouch for each of their servers to be setup correctly? Wow :) TC shows file date, so if that differs from gallery, the latter obviously must be using Exif. Which again makes my "server time zone /DST differences" theory unlikely, as sync wouldn't touch the Exif data. Not sure if Dropbox would, OTOH, try to "correct" things... Can you check with an Exif viewer?

Comment: @Izzy I think we can take Dropbox out of the equation here, since I only mentioned it to avoid being redirected to the people who complained that accessing images via USB `touch`es the files and [alters their date](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/14189/30298), and I doubt that Dropbox alters files on the phone during upload. Just *after* seeing that some of the images got mixed up (on the phone), I hooked up my phone to the PC to inspect dates on the images and I couldn't spot anything fishy. I'll also compare Exif data a bit later, just to be sure, but I doubt I'll find anything relevant.

Comment: I'm not really expecting any changes in Exif either. But ruling things out helps to find what's left: *When you have excluded the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.* (Arthur Conan Doyle) :)